# VBA: How to access a 2D array inside of an array?

Tags: arrays, vba, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I have an array of 2D arrays. I'm looking to assign a variable to one of the 2D arrays:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA3Lf.png

`a = arry(0)(0)` gives a "subscript out of range" error. Is there no way to access this array?? I'd like to copy it without having to loop through elements and rewrite to another array.

Comment: Try `arry(0)(0, 0)`

Comment: That would get me the first element of arry(0)(0). I'm looking to get the array itself.

Comment: Then you want `a=arry(0)`

Comment: @Kaan , Please do not edit the question to incorporate the solution. You can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and also [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)... Also, to access/ slice the first row in the first 2D array stored in 1D array indexed 0 based, try `Application.Index(arry(0),1,0)`  ..You can get this in a 1D array as `array1D = Application.Index(arry(0),1,0)`

Comment: @Naresh , thank you- that's what I was looking for. How do I mark your comment as the accepted solution? Finding the UI here to be pretty bad....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may have also ran into this, the answer is that arry(0)(0) does not actually exist, so there is no way to reference it. The way to access the whole 2D array is arry(0). I was looking to access just one row of the 2D array as its own array. To get just this row as a 1D array, you can use `array1D = Application.Index(arry(0),1,0)`